# Advanced Installed SQL Server Failed to establish connection

Tags: sql-server, advanced-installer

I'm using Advanced Installer Architect 17.5 to create an `.exe` setup file. During my installation process, I need to run some SQL Server queries.

When it comes to creating a SQL connection, I could not find the right configuration to help me pass the connectivity test.

I've tried many different scenarios, I've used SQL Server or SQL Server Native Client 10.0 to connect to the database. I've also used Windows authentication mode (Trusted Connection/Impersonate user) or database logins, but all of them lead to an error

> Failed to establish connection

in the test process.

Can somebody point out what is my error in this process?

I've brought screen shot for details. Please not I've also disabled `Impersonate User` and tried to login but all of them failed.

[image]

I've used many configurations for Server parameter such as `.` or `.\ServerName` or `local`.

I've also tried SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2017. Using the same parameters I can connect to server using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: you would better try to address this on [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=fac3adabf50f0241e2795cccd00f47bc) forums.

Comment: @herman.smn since there many questions I this tag I tried to follow the case here. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple of things first (If you haven't done them already):

1. Make sure your server is configured to allow remote connections. You can check this in SQL Management Studio, right-click on your server, click 'Properties' and go to the 'Connections' section.
2. Make sure the ODBC driver to connect to SQL Server is installed. You can get it from here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15